# Derived class constructor taking base class object

Tags: java, android

I am trying to extend `BitmapDrawable`

```
public class CenterClampedBitmapDrawable extends BitmapDrawable
```

I want to have a constructor that takes a BitmapDrawable and uses it to set my baseclass properties.

```
public CenterClampedBitmapDrawable(BitmapDrawable src) {
```

I can not work out how to do this, if `BitmapDrawable` had a copy constructor then I think I would be OK but it has not got one.

I am fairly new to java and this has me stumped, it's trivial in C++

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd have to do that manually in the subclass constructor:

```
this.setFoo(src.getFoo());
this.setBar(src.getBar());
```

Perhaps you can use some reflection utility, like apache commons-beanutils (don't know if this particular one works on android), but if the properties are not too many, the manual approach is better.

Comment: That sounds painfully...  but I guess if that's the only way I will give it a go.

Comment: I failed to get the beanutils to work. As there were not too many getters and setters I did it manualy.  In the position I am using this a lot of the getters were returning null, which the setter did not cope with.  I have ended up with just 3 things being coppied over.

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement the constructor in your new class to copy properties.

Use Apache commons BeanUtils copyProperties in your constructor if you don't want to write all the getter/setter calls.

http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/api/org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanUtils.html